# Iterate over a 2D array wrapped in an object

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, multidimensional-array

I have a problem I have been researching for a while on the internet but can not seem to find anything that could help me reach a conclusion.

I have a class **Grid**. Grid stores a 2D array of type **Cell**.

```
public class Grid implements Iterable<Cell>{
    private Cell[][] grid;
```

And I have class **Main**. I want to be able to iterate over the 2D array **grid** inside the **Grid** object, form the **Main** in such fashion:

```
public class Main {
Grid grid;

    for(Cell c: grid){
        //do something
    }
}
```

I can't simply add:

```
public Iterator<Cell> iterator() {
    retrun grid.iterator();
}
```

Inside my **Grid** class because it returns an error.

I do not want the **Cell** objects to hold the coordinates, I would like the 2D array to represent the coordinate system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell[][] doesn't implement Iterator. You should create a GridIterator inner class in Grid that implements Iterator and whose next() and hasNext() return whatever you consider to be the "next" Cell, until the grid has been traversed.

Comment: I'm off writing custom iterator then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Cell[] row : grid) {
  for(Cell cell : row) { 
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

You can't iterate over the individual elements of a two-dimensional array directly, but you can iterate over the rows, and then iterate over the elements of the rows.

Comment: I tried my best to convey what I was asking, I want to iterate inside the **Main** class, not inside the **Grid** class.